# how to increase datatable height in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I'm facing this issue I want to see the first 10 rows but it gives scrolling by default.

```
datatable(data, options = list(), class = "display", fillContainer = T, 
       width = NULL, height = 1000, editable = FALSE)
```

[image]

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome this issue I set `scrollY = "565px"` in the `options = list()`